# How to make the app running when screen closed in android device

Tags: android

My app MainActivity have banner、video,but when using gotoSleep,after amonent,open the screen,they will stop play and scroll,how to make the app running when screen open after screen close
my code is :

```
public ScreenUtils(Context contx) {
    this.mContext = contx;
    this.pManager = (PowerManager)this.mContext.getSystemService("power");
    this.wakeLock = this.pManager.newWakeLock(268435462, "TAG");
    this.wakeLock.setReferenceCounted(false);
    this.wakeLock.acquire();
}

public boolean lcdPowerOff() {
    if (this.wakeLock.isHeld()) {
        this.wakeLock.release();
    }

    this.pManager.goToSleep(SystemClock.uptimeMillis());
    return true;
}

public boolean lcdPowerOn() {
    this.wakeLock.acquire();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

don't use wakeLock, Android's power control is very strict now
When you reopen the app, you can restart the player in the onResume lifecycle

Comment: but i need the screen close,have another way close the screen？